# What do I need to do in PHP so that the imagepstext () and imagepsloadfont () functions work?

Tags: php, image

I am creating a catalog for a collection of fonts and a large part of it are Post Script. I found these functions (imagepsloadfont e imagepstext), however, already test on several servers (bitnami, UsbWebserver, Apache2triad, etc). I also tested directly on my hosting server (Host Gator) and always gives error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagepsloadfont () in
>   /home/eiboc860/public_html/post_script/manual.php on line 6 Fatal
>   error: Call to undefined function imagepstext () in
>   /home/eiboc860/public_html/post_script/manual.php on line 7

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(350, 45);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 349, 44, $white);
$font = imagepsloadfont("12 Sabon Bold 07232.pfb"); // or locate your .pfb files on your machine
imagepstext($im, "Testing... It worked!", $font, 32, $white, $black, 32, 32);
imagepsfreefont($font);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

I've tried with all 5.x versions.
Would anyone know to tell me if there is any feature to install for the functions to work or some other method for printing with Post Script fonts in image?

Comment: This function is only available if PHP is compiled using --with-t1lib[=DIR] .To enable GD-support configure PHP --with-gd[=DIR] , where DIR is the GD base install directory. To use the recommended bundled version of the GD library, use the configure option --with-gd . GD library requires libpng and libjpeg to compile.

In Windows, you'll include the GD2 DLL php_gd2.dll as an extension in php.ini. sorce: http://php.net/manual/ro/image.installation.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php

Comment: You can also leverage composer to do dependency checking, but that may be a bit beyond your immediate question. Also, you can use `function_exists('imagepsloadfont')` to avoid the fatal error (but this won't help you get the function to exist, only to know your script won't work before trying to run it).

Comment: I checked my PHP.INI and it has this extension enabled. Even the file from this library is in the "ext" directory.
extension=php_gd2.dll